# Javascript & PHP I need advice on how to seperate data_type before sending to server

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

I am trying to write a web game using [WebSocket API](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm)

In this game containing two players, I am running two jobs through one server:

- one is a simple game where users can choose between two options
- the other is a chat box.

Both of these two jobs will send data to a server script to process the data.

To send this data, I use WebSocket's method `.send(data)`. My problem is that two jobs have to be handled separately in the server; but the `.send(data)` method does not have a parameter for me to differentiate `event_name`, so the server will treat the two submitted data equally.

Please suggest me a way to tell the server to **differentiate** two jobs. I have thought about putting a prefix (ex. `chat_*`, `game_*`, but if the users know my prefix they can screw up my server.

What should I try next?

Comment: If you're writing the game in javascript users will always be able to send "false" data to your server.  However, when you get the data on the server side, you'll sanitize the data with php functions (only allowing what you expect to be sent).  In other words, using the prefix method as above would seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah prefix should work just fine. .send(data) method also take extra care to handle bad data input.